# Is it possible to encase an invalid HTML snippet in a HTML document such that the snippet does not affect the page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display chunks of HTML from a DB, and sometimes it is a portion of the entire HTML page, so may be invalid, since I may be returning the first 500 chars. I may get:

```
<h1>test</h1><div id="
```

At present this corrupts the containing page.

Can this be wrapped up in someway, by some tags, such that it does not corrupt the containing HTML.

My initial idea was something like:

```
<div>
    <h1>test</h1><div id="
</div>
```

However this does not work.

Also it would be ideal if any valid HTML did work as expected, so the above would look like:

> **Test**

It may not be possible, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Why would you get partial html from the db ?

Comment: Hi patsy. Basically, I would get a partial return since I can only display a portion of the HTML on a summary page, a taster if you like so I would expect to see something like "This is my test page...." etc.

Comment: The closest I can think of to what you're asking for would be to put the dodgy HTML in an [**iframe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) (might be tricky to do - maybe best done via JS). However that's a sticky-tape cludge: you'd be better off sanitizing the HTML on the server side. I'd look at how well-tested blog platforms like Wordpress and Drupal do this on the server side, then adapt that for whatever you're using. I'm 90% sure Drupal Views has some helper function that removes broken HTML from snippets like these while leaving unbroken HTML in place.

Comment: That has given me an idea. Possible I could use HTML Tidy to sanitize? I use that to create valid XHTML from HTML. Perhaps it will do the same here? Now for some experimentation.

Comment: May still have a problem with HTML Tidy, as this creates a full XHTML document and not a valid HTML fragment. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of what Server Side/Client Side language you are using, but I assume you are using PHP, you need to use `strip_tags()` to strip all the HTML text first, and than try echoing it..

```
<p class="static_wrapper">
   <?php echo substr(strip_tags($fetched_row['column_name']),0,100).'...'; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: I am actually using MVC3 asp.net. However I do get your concept. The issue I see here is that one will not be able to display the valid HTML that does exist. It will need to all be text. Am I correct?

Comment: @SamJolly exactly, I am using `strip_tags()` to strip the tags from the string and than am chopping the text from 0-100 characters

Comment: I can use Regex to strip the HTML. For the moment this may be my best solution.

Comment: @SamJolly It may be complicated, as tags may be incomplete.. or some tags might contain classes, ids etc...

Comment: To be honest the text produced is not great to read since all the formatting has gone. The regex I used was @"<[^>]*>" which worked. Perhaps another way of looking at it is to download all of the fragment html into the page, then in someone have the HTML or JS display just a portion. So the page HTML is now valid, it is just the user just sees a portion. CMS systems deal with this issue. Perhaps there is an HTML Viewer widget in JQuery etc?? with a vertical scroll bar?

Comment: @SamJolly jQuery seems decent, but it will break if JavaScript is turned off or the library failed to load in certain circumstances, but anyways, these factors are minimal..

Comment: I do use the CKEditor RTE control, so am progressing this now in readonly mode, so I now get all of the HTML , but in a contained space which was the design requirement. Thanks for your help